# if(c.get_name(&name) && name && !strcmp(name, contName))

Tags: c++

```
if(c.get_name(&name) && name && !strcmp(name, contName))
```

Can Someone Kindly tell me what this line Means in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `c` has a name and it is equal to `contName` then.....

If `c` has a name           - `c.get_name(&name) && name` - Get `c`'s name and ensure it exists.
it is equal to `contName`   - `&& !strcmp(name, contName)`- `strcmp` returns 0 for equality.

Comment: @sumitkang you are most welcome! Please consider marking this as answer if this has answered satisfactorily. You can click the arrow symbol to the left.